# VBA Calculations Turning Back On Mid Execution

Tags: vba, excel

I'm running a large macro that includes various sub queries and functions.

Despite having the standard code to turn off calculations while the macro is running, somehow calculations are turned back on during the code execution.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

I've added the above code the beginning of each major sub but still have the same issue. There's one point in the macro where I calculate the application to update a worksheet stored value, but I can't imagine that's what's causing it.

```
application.Calculate
```

Trying to find if there's a work around.

Comment: Do you have the line `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` at the end of some of your subroutines?  If you call several subs and some end with this, you need to get a bit fancy about keeping track of the `Application.Calculation` state.

Comment: No I only turn calculations back on at the end of the primary routine.